# SQL Server: Count of clients in the office by hour

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL 2012, trying to get a count of clients that are present in the office using an arrival time and a departure time by hour (00:01-01:00, 01:01-02:00, etc). I am looking to start counting the client at it's arrival hour, for every hour until the hour of it's departure. 
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Clients(

GUID NUMERIC(16,0),
ArrivalTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
DepartTime DATETIME NOT NULL)

GO

INSERT INTO #Clients (GUID, ArrivalTime, DepartTime)
SELECT '9158300270', '2016-01-17 00:02:00.000', '2016-01-17 01:39:32.407' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158400270', '2016-01-17 00:05:00.000', '2016-01-17 02:55:09.920' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158600270', '2016-01-17 00:14:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:25:14.860' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158700270', '2016-01-17 00:44:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:37:51.700' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158800270', '2016-01-17 01:58:00.000', '2016-01-17 02:35:14.883' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158900270', '2016-01-17 02:04:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:26:20.353' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9159100270', '2016-01-17 02:44:00.000', '2016-01-17 4:57:00.157'
```

I am looking to get results that displays as follows:

```
00-01 | 01-02 | 02-03 | 03-04 | 04-05
4       5       6       4       1
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you need it pivoted by the columns like that or can you live with two columns and multiple rows?

Comment: I can settle for two columns and multiple rows. I can always PIVOT it if need be. Thanks!

Comment: Can your data span across several dates, or it is always confined to one day?

Comment: It will span across multiple dates to get a better picture of peak hour.

Comment: Can arrival and departure be different day?

Comment: Yes the arrival and departure can be on different days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            h.DayHour,
            COUNT(c.ArrivalTime) People
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 AS DayHour
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 3
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 4
        ) h
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #Clients c ON 
            CAST(c.ArrivalTime AS TIME) <= CAST(CAST(h.DayHour + 1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':00' AS TIME) AND
            CAST(c.DepartTime AS TIME) > CAST(CAST(h.DayHour AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':00' AS TIME)
        GROUP BY
            h.DayHour
    ) c
PIVOT (MIN(People) FOR DayHour IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])) p;
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired results that the OP posted.

Comment: I am not so much worried, in this query, with the time spent in the office as I am the peak hours of the day. I am looking to find the busiest hours to see when more staff needs to be helping.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I'll have to generate a bogus 24 record derived table and cross join it using a between with the arrival date and depart date. I'll rework it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea. This really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```
; WITH a AS ( SELECT *, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), arrivaltime, 108)atime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), departtime, 108) dtime 
             FROM #clients )
SELECT count( CASE WHEN atime <= '01:00' THEN 1 END) AS '00-01', count( CASE WHEN atime <= '02:00' AND dtime>='01:00' THEN 1 END) AS '01-02', 
       count( CASE WHEN atime <='03:00' AND dtime>='02:00' THEN 1 END) AS '02-03', count( CASE WHEN atime <= '04:00' AND dtime >='03:00' THEN 1 END) AS '03-04', 
       count( CASE WHEN atime <='05:00' AND dtime>='04:00' THEN 1 END) AS '04-05' 
       FROM a
```

Comment: The enter code here part of the otherwise nice sql, what code could f.ex. be inserted there?

Answer (score 0):

This feels a little heavy, like it could be optimized, made more elegant, or succinct, but it does return the right results. What I found most challenging was that the range of hourly periods is dynamic, so that's why a loop is used. I feel like there's a better solution to the loop, but it is evading me.

```
CREATE TABLE #Clients(

GUID NUMERIC(16,0),
ArrivalTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
DepartTime DATETIME NOT NULL)

GO

INSERT INTO #Clients (GUID, ArrivalTime, DepartTime)
SELECT '9158300270', '2016-01-17 00:02:00.000', '2016-01-17 01:39:32.407' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158400270', '2016-01-17 00:05:00.000', '2016-01-17 02:55:09.920' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158600270', '2016-01-17 00:14:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:25:14.860' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158700270', '2016-01-17 00:44:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:37:51.700' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158800270', '2016-01-17 01:58:00.000', '2016-01-17 02:35:14.883' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158900270', '2016-01-17 02:04:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:26:20.353' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9159100270', '2016-01-17 02:44:00.000', '2016-01-17 4:57:00.157'


DECLARE @MinArrive datetime = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, MIN(ArrivalTime)), 0) FROM #Clients);
DECLARE @MaxDepart datetime = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, MAX(DepartTime)) + 1, 0) FROM #Clients);

CREATE TABLE #Results
    (
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime
    );

DECLARE @i datetime = @MinArrive;

WHILE @i < @MaxDepart
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results
        (
        StartTime,
        EndTime
        )
    VALUES
        (
        @i,
        DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @i)
        );

    SET @i = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @i);
END

SELECT
    r.StartTime,
    r.EndTime,
    COUNT(c.GUID) PeopleInOffice
FROM
    #Results r
    LEFT JOIN
    #Clients c
    ON
        c.ArrivalTime < r.EndTime
        AND
        c.DepartTime > r.StartTime
GROUP BY
    r.StartTime,
    r.EndTime;

DROP TABLE #Results;
DROP TABLE #Clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shriop really helped me out on this one and gave me the idea. But I thought I would post what ended up working for me on this one.

```
CREATE TABLE #Clients(

GUID NUMERIC(16,0),
ArrivalTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
DepartTime DATETIME NOT NULL)

GO

INSERT INTO #Clients (GUID, ArrivalTime, DepartTime)
SELECT '9158300270', '2016-01-17 00:02:00.000', '2016-01-17 01:39:32.407' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158400270', '2016-01-17 00:05:00.000', '2016-01-17 02:55:09.920' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158600270', '2016-01-17 00:14:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:25:14.860' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158700270', '2016-01-17 00:44:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:37:51.700' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158800270', '2016-01-17 01:58:00.000', '2016-01-17 02:35:14.883' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9158900270', '2016-01-17 02:04:00.000', '2016-01-17 03:26:20.353' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '9159100270', '2016-01-17 02:44:00.000', '2016-01-17 4:57:00.157'

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '01:00:00.000' THEN '1'    END) AS '0-1'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '02:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '01:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '1-2'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '03:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '02:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '2-3'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '04:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '03:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '3-4'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '05:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '04:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '4-5'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '06:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '05:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '5-6'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '07:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '06:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '6-7'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '08:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '07:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '7-8'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '09:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '08:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '8-9'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '10:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '09:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '9-10'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '11:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '10:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '10-11'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '12:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '11:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '11-12'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '13:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '12:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '12-13'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '14:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '13:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '13-14'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '15:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '14:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '14-15'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '16:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '15:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '15-16'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '17:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '16:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '16-17'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '18:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '17:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '17-18'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '19:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '18:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '18-19'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '20:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '19:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '19-20'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '21:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '20:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '20-21'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '22:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '21:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '21-22'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '23:00:00.000' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '22:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '22-23'
,COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(ArrivalTime AS TIME) < '23:59:58.999' AND CAST(DepartTime AS TIME) > '23:00:00.000' THEN '1' END) AS '23-24'
FROM #Clients

DROP TABLE #Clients
```